# Typescript modules compile duplicate variables

Tags: typescript

Given the following `Typescript` it seems to compile multiple variables with the same name.

I am including a brief example that assumes two seperate files used with the same top level module name. I am compiling into a single file.

**File 1**

```
module Parent {
    export module Child1 {
        export class TestClass {
        }
    }
}
```

**File 2**

```
module Parent {
    export module Child2 {
        export class TestClass {
        }
    }
}
```

**Compiles To**

```
var Parent;
(function (Parent) {
    (function (Child1) {
        var TestClass = (function () {
            function TestClass() {
            }
            return TestClass;
        })();
        Child1.TestClass = TestClass;
    })(Parent.Child1 || (Parent.Child1 = {}));
    var Child1 = Parent.Child1;
})(Parent || (Parent = {}));

var Parent;
(function (Parent) {
    (function (Child2) {
        var TestClass = (function () {
            function TestClass() {
            }
            return TestClass;
        })();
        Child2.TestClass = TestClass;
    })(Parent.Child2 || (Parent.Child2 = {}));
    var Child2 = Parent.Child2;
})(Parent || (Parent = {}));
```

Notice the duplicate `var Parent;` statements. How do I prevent this? Or is this not an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I prevent this? Or is this not an issue?

You cannot prevent it. Its not an issue. If you were using pure JS you would still do at the top of your file:

```
var Parent = Parent || {};
```

TypeScript is just being safer + the following allows you to do local scope variables (you would still do the same in JS if you wanted a local scope).

```
var Parent;
(function (Parent) {
   // local scope only 
})(Parent || (Parent = {}));
```